# Imgs don't get inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div container where i want to put two images, one above the other, where the only visible image will be the one checked. I give my container `position:relative` and my imgs `position:absolute;`, so it will be absolute in relation to the container. But instead, all the content of the figure tag are going away from the container, and i don't know why.

Here's what i have: https://jsfiddle.net/rckecf2b/1/

Comment: Can you please explain the layout you would like to obtain?

Comment: CSS basics: Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal layout flow – it does not affect the dimensions of its parent any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that givin' height:200px to #container-fim-ap solved the problem.

```
#container-fim-ap{
    border:solid 5px #ABB7B7;
    width:80%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    border-radius:2%;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
  position:relative;
    height: 200px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rckecf2b/2/ Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to have the div have the absolute position and the images relative to the parent, like so

When something has an absolute position, it ignores other set positions. If you want to have the positions *seem* absolute within a div, you need them to be ***relative***

```
#container-fim-ap{
    border:solid 5px #ABB7B7;
    width:50%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    border-radius:2%;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
}
#container-fim-ap figure{
        position: relative;
        left:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rckecf2b/3/

play around with it a little